# How to get json string from a website using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, python-re

I am trying to get image links of the products from the [website](https://www.trendyol.com/). I can get image info on some of the products. However, I can't get some of them. In the code URL1 is working but URL2 throws "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError". I think the problem is I cant parse the JSON string. I am not good at regular expression. How can I get JSON string?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adu3R.jpg)

Code

```
import re,json,requests
url1 =  "https://www.trendyol.com/samsung/akilli-smart-air-sihirli-led-tv-televizyon-kumandasi-yerine-tuslu-kumanda-1078-p-43447565?boutiqueId=61&merchantId=384846"
url2 = "https://www.trendyol.com/samsung/k-ve-m-serisi-uyumlu-led-lcd-tv-akilli-kumandasi-bn59-01259b-p-45735139?boutiqueId=61&merchantId=115135"
r = requests.get(url2)
data = json.loads(re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?);', r.text).group(1))
images = ['https://www.trendyol.com' + img for img in data['product']['images']]
print(images)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex is a better match for your given urls as it terminates at the end of the nested dictionaries and before the start of the next block.

```
import re,json,requests

url1 =  "https://www.trendyol.com/samsung/akilli-smart-air-sihirli-led-tv-televizyon-kumandasi-yerine-tuslu-kumanda-1078-p-43447565?boutiqueId=61&merchantId=384846"
url2 = "https://www.trendyol.com/samsung/k-ve-m-serisi-uyumlu-led-lcd-tv-akilli-kumandasi-bn59-01259b-p-45735139?boutiqueId=61&merchantId=115135"

for url in [url1, url2]:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?\}\});', r.text).group(1))
    images = ['https://www.trendyol.com' + img for img in data['product']['images']]
    print(images)
    print("")
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
}

r = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/samsung/k-ve-m-serisi-uyumlu-led-lcd-tv-akilli-kumandasi-bn59-01259b-p-45735139?boutiqueId=61&merchantId=115135')
soup = BeautifulSoup ((r.text).encode('utf-8'))

img = soup.findAll ('img')
for x in img:
    print(x['src'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that way before. It is getting low-resolution images. I need high-resolution images of the product.